# How do I see which LLVM library have to link with to resolve PassManagerBuilder::addGlobalExtension()?

Tags: c++, llvm

How do I see which LLVM library have to link with to resolve PassManagerBuilder::addGlobalExtension()?

I've already included `llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader)` in the CMakeLists.txt.

However, I still get a link error for the symbol above.

In general, how to I look up which libraries I need to include to resolve certain symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method PassManagerBuilder::addGlobalExtension() declared and defined in 
include/llvm/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.h and lib/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.cpp respectively. Live it in library libLLVMipo.a, hence you need add to llvm_map_components_to_libnames the string ipo:

```
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs ipo ...)
```